# I just started using Python 3 a few hours ago, and for some reason I can't get a while True loop to work after time.sleep

Tags: python, time, while-loop, terminal

When I typed

```
time.sleep(10)\
while True:
```

Python gave me an error message saying

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    while True:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is probably a stupid question, but how do I get past this? Also I'm using MacOS terminal because my mid-2011 MacBook Air is too old to install Xcode. Also, yes, I imported the time module.

Comment: Why the backslash? Are you using the REPL?

Comment: @AMC I'm using MacOS terminal.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want the it to wait before the loop starts.

Comment: The trailing backslash on the first line cancels the newline, making Python think it's all one line.

Comment: remove the backslash from first line. Because of backslash, prompt is assuming time.sleep(10) and while True as one command

Comment: "MacOS terminal" does not explain why you're trying to use a backslash in that spot.  That's simply illegal syntax.

Comment: With MacOS terminal, pressing the enter key runs the code, but I've read that the backslash will start a new line.

Comment: nevermind, i managed to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the backslash at the end of the first line. If you remove it, python doesn't raise the SyntaxError any more.

```
    import time
    time.sleep(10)
    while True:
        pass
```